# Load data into neo4j in windows environment

Tags: windows, neo4j

I am new to Neo4j but am excited about the possibilities.  I have used a spreadsheet to create a script file that contains Cypher statements to create nodes and edges.  My problem is that all of the documentation I have been able to find relies on Unix/Linux commands to load the data into the database.  We are on a Windows environment that does not recognize these commands.  I have tried using Cygwin to get around this but I get kernal errors whenever I try to run the commands.  I have also tried copying the Cypher queries into the web ui but it seems I can only run one command at a time and there are over 600 commands.  Multiple commands give an error when starting to read the second line.

Is there a way to batch load these cypher commands from a windows environment and if so how?  If not is there another format such as CSV or REST that I need to use to load the data and if so what would be the Windows processes I should use?

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide...

Answer (score 0):

When I started with Neo4J, I used Excel on Windows. I simply scripted the neo4j statements to load nodes and ran them in via the web based UI on localhost:7474. Neo4J is agnostic to the OS as it runs on a JVM; when you say Linux, I'm guessing your mean the curl command?

Have you checked out Michael Hunger's [Neo4J Batch Import](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import) project?

See also Max's presentation [Overview on importing](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/import)

[Import Large Graphs](http://iordanis.com/post/22677357894/import-large-graphs-to-neo4j-with-spring-data-fast)